# How to disable Excel built-in RibbonButton?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, ribbon, built-in

Is it possible to set an excel 2010 built in RibbonButton to enabled=false from an excel VSTO Add-In?

I tried the following:

```
CommandBarControls controlls=Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CommandBars.FindControls(MsoControlType.msoControlButton, 7374, null, false);
/// 7374 is the office control id of the control I want to access

foreach (CommandBarControl control in controlls)
{
    control.Enabled = false;
}
```

But this seems to work only for the right click context menu. And not for the ribbon buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only disable tabs, not controls unless you use the [`startFromScratch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.officeribbon.startfromscratch.aspx) Ribbon UI attribute. [See MSDN for reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633442%28office.11%29.aspx#odc_office2007_DisplayHideRibbonControls_UsinggetVisibleAttributeBuiltinTabs).

Also see [Ribbon XML FAQ](http://www.rondebruin.nl/ribbon.htm) for good resources on Excel Ribbon manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether this would help you, but for a custom ribbon, you implement the `getEnabled` callback with a Ribbon XML.

In the XML:

```
<button id="btnMyButton" ... getEnabled="OnMyButton_GetEnabled" onAction="..."/>
```

In the code-behind:

```
public bool OnMyButton_GetEnabled(Office.IRibbonControl rControl)
{
  // return true or false to enable or disable 
}
```

You need to call the `IRibbonUI.Invalidate()` method if you need to forcefully call these callbacks (for example, when your enable/disable state variables are set due to some other event).

Btw, the Ribbon Designer interface (on VS 2010) doesn't seem to offer the ability to implement the `getEnabled` callback.