# How to get the "Data Validation" CommandBarButton object?

Tags: excel, vsto, add-in, office-2007, commandbar

I need to hide the **Data Validation** button when user switch to particular sheet, but I cannot locate this button in `Application.CommandBars`.

I have tried to loop out all the `CommandBar` object and its control name but still not found, has anyone tried this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel 2007, the **Data Validation** button is in the Ribbon UI (*not command bars*) - you won't be able to disable it without overwriting the existing Ribbon group (*GroupDataTools*). See this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9625994/175679) regarding how to overwrite existing Ribbon groups. To locate the Control IDs of menu groups in the Ribbon, you can [download this list of control ids from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3582).

Comment: How to get the Ribbon UI control in code?  I'm using VS2005 Excel project, is it able to get the object in `ThisAddIn_Startup`?

Comment: To replace the Ribbon Group, see [this website which describes how to properly modify existing [Ribbon Groups](http://www.rondebruin.nl/xmlribbongroups.htm). You can also find [more information on the Office Fluent UI here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905530.aspx).